# How to change my background of the screen for my view

Tags: android, background-image, textcolor

I have simple job to do. I have to create an Help page for my android application. On that page I want to just put a full page of text of green color with some background image. Can anybody suggest me how can I do this in my XML file. Either in GraphicalLayoutMode or XML mode.

Please suggest what are the components required to this type of Help page...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
android:background="#0abcde"
```

to set a color

```
android:background="@drawable/filename"
```

to set a image background.

use these tags for your layout parent view.

Comment: I set the parent view as a scrollview. Then I put a TextView to display my help text. But the string resource i use to put in the textview has limited characters. My help text is large. Please provide some suggestion...

Comment: tell me what exactly do u need. how to change background or how to arrange your layout. in case of layout please edit your question to tell us more info on what you need.

Comment: actually your answer worked for me to change the background. Now I faced new problem as my comment above. I should create new question for this. Sorry for the clutter. my new question here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7702797/how-to-arrange-my-layout-for-a-large-text-in-android