# How to arrange my layout for a large text in android?

Tags: android, scrollview, multilinestring

I set the parent view as a scrollview. Then I put a TextView to display my help text. But the string resource i use to put in the textview has limited characters. My help text is large. Please provide some suggestion...

Comment: My parent view is a scrollview. I want to put my help text into the scrollview with certain image background and forground text color as green. I used the string resource but my whole text for help page does not fit into the string. so how to do it...

Comment: Do you want larger text in single line...Or multiple line text in Parent Scroll View

Comment: I need multiple lines of text in my scrollview. For that I created a string resource and put my help text into that. But the string can't contain my whole help text. It contains a few only. thats my problem

Comment: did you try populating help text dynamically? using setText() ?

Comment: Yashwanth Kumar : please post your comment as answer and then i will accept it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got it solved by dynamically populating the TextView